# javascript function does not work when used <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

Given the following code:

```js
function move()
{
    dom = document.getElementById('image');
    dom.style.top=event.clientY+"px";
    dom.style.left=event.clientX+"px";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Program 3</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pr3.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onmousedown="move();">
  <img src="image.jpg" id="image" width="300px" height="200px" style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px;"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Edit**

The image only moves when clicked on the image. But when clicked outside the image, it does not move.

However, without `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it moves wherever clicked inside the browser window and not explicitly on the image.

Comment: use event.x or other official properties instead of the outmoded quirky layout clientX. it's probably setting "nullpx" or "undefinedpx" for the value as of now, which gets silently discarded.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: It works in mozilla 32 for me. what browser are you using.

Comment: @userDEV I'm in chrome 38.+. And not working in mozilla 33.1.

Comment: I tried it in chrome 38.0.2125.111 m and it works.  Windows 7 OS.  What OS do you have?

Comment: Windows. But its still not working with <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hm4fg6gx/

Comment: Works fine in firefox

Comment: It works, only when I click on the image. But it doesn't work when I click outside the image.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want is available to you via jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/draggable

Comment: Nothing else exists but the image. By positioning it absolutely, the body shrinks to zero.

Comment: If you want to be able to click anywhere and the image will follow your cursor, you will have to contain the image in a "Stage" that could be a div or something that is the full height and width of the area that you want the image to be able to move around in.

Comment: Note that I understand your problem, **but** your working no-doctype case can't be seen in a snippet even if you remove the explicit doctype, because snippets (and jsFiddle pages) automatically insert a `<!DOCTYPE ...>` of some kind (at least that's what happens in Chrome). You can't get quirks mode, it seems.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for understanding. I don't know why I am getting down votes. I was being genuine here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in "quirks mode" body height is set to 100%, while in "standards mode" it is determined by its content. So without doctype(rendering in quirks mode) whole page area is body - so it is clickable, but in "standards mode" it is only image...

if you want you can also do this in "standards mode", by applying following css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wrHS3b8nQ9tfi5AMWqoE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements to not affect the size of their containing element. Consider a case where we use a red-colored `<div>` instead of `<body>` as the clickable element:

```js
function move() {
    dom = document.getElementById('image');
    dom.style.top=event.clientY+"px";
    dom.style.left=event.clientX+"px";
}
```

```css
div { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
    <div onmousedown="move();">
      <img src="image.jpg" id="image" width="300px" height="200px" style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px;"/>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

This snippet should contain a red-colored `<div>`, but it doesn't, because the `<div>` is empty or anything that would cause it to have a size greater than 0. The image it contains is absolutely-positioned, which does not affect the size.

Now consider a similar `<div>` with a CSS-specified size:

```js
function move() {
    dom = document.getElementById('image');
    dom.style.top=event.clientY+"px";
    dom.style.left=event.clientX+"px";
}
```

```css
div {
      background-color: red;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
    <div onmousedown="move();">
      <img src="image.jpg" id="image" width="300px" height="200px" style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px;"/>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Now the div is larger than zero, and clicking inside produces the expected result.

this is why your `<body>` clicks don't work: the `<body>` has a width and height of 0. If you instead place the `onclick` listener on the `<html>` element (which is full-width and full-height by default) or on an element with non-zero dimensions, you'll see your code works. I'm not sure I'd advise putting binding click listeners on the `<html>` element; I would advise using a CSS-sized `<div>`.